# EF6 unique constraint on foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've got the following scenario:

```
public class Book {
        [Key]
        public string Isbn { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author {
    public int  AuthorId { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking to insert books, and associated authors if needed. I have the following naive code, which breaks (pretty much expected):

```
var author = _ctx.Authors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == command.Author);

if (author == null)
    author = new Author { Name = command.Author };

var book = new Book
{
    Isbn = command.Id,
    Title = command.Title,
    Stock = command.Count,
    Author = author
};

_ctx.Books.Add(book);

await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

What I'm seeing is that sometimes, the FirstOrDefault is returning null, but the insert is failing due to violation of the unique index on the author name. Is there some EF trickery that'll allow this to happen in a simplistic way? I guess I could use a stored proc, but would like to do it client side if possible.

Comment: The only reason I can see that this would break is if you are adding multiple books simultaneously and the `Author` is added by another process between when you look it up and when the item is added to the collection.  The simplest way to handle that sort of concurrency issue, in my opinion, would be to catch the exception, attach the book to the author that is now in the Db, and then resubmit.

Comment: 1. did you try?
Author.Books.Add(book);
ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
2. Add to book:
public int  AuthorId { get; set; }
public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

Comment: Claies's observation is correct...the race is exactly the issue, and I'm trying to find a workaround. @W92, yes...tried that. same race condition arises. The issue is on the author insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying various things, I've gone with the following:

```
var author = _ctx.Authors.SqlQuery(
    "with data as (select @author as [name]) " +
    "merge Authors a " +
    "using data s on s.[name] = a.[name] " +
    "when not matched by target " +
    "then insert([name]) values(s.[name]); select * from Authors where [name]=@author", new SqlParameter("author", command.Author)).Single();


var book = new Book
{
    Isbn = command.Id,
    Title = command.Title,
    Stock = command.Count,
    Author = author
};

_ctx.Books.Add(book);

await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

While not pretty, this does prevent the race condition between the author check and insertion using db native features. ORMs and leaky abstractions, eh :)

I guess I could put the book insert in there too, or make the whole thing a sproc. If anybody comes up with an ORM native approach that caters to this scenario, I'm all ears :)